# SD Card and Configuration Settings

Tags: android, sd-card, permission-denied

Oh Dear, Please help before I have no more hair on my head!

Firstly, here is my code:

```
private void copyDatabase() {
    if(!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){ 
        Toast.makeText(this, "External SD card not mounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 
    //Toast Message Always appears
    try {
        InputStream in = getAssets().open("Asset_Directory");


        File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Asset_Directory");
        outFile.createNewFile();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);


        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        Log.i("AssetCaptureActivity","Database has been transferred");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("AssetCaptureActivity","Could not open the file");
    }
}`
```

As you can see:
I copied a database file into my Assets folder. 
Now I want to copy it to a virtual sd card so that I can edit the database.
I have added the WRITE permissions in my manifest.
I read that I need to change something in my [run configuration] setting - but what?

I keep getting Permission Denied and It says my sd card is not mounted.

Please help!

Comment: U trying this on emulator or device ?

Comment: Yes I am, I created a sd card in my avd

Comment: Like your way of requesting (help before I have no more hair on my head!) but not able to help you

Answer (score 2):

You can use following methods to determine whether external storage is available or not

```
/**
 * @return <ul>
 *         <li><b>true: </b>If external storage is available</li>
 *         <li><b>false: </b>If external storage is not available</li>
 *         </ul>
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {

    boolean isAvailable = false;
    try {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)
                || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            // We can read the media
            isAvailable = true;
        } else {
            // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states,
            // but all we need
            // to know is we can not read
            isAvailable = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return isAvailable;
}

/**
 * @return <ul>
 *         <li><b>true: </b>If external storage is writable</li>
 *         <li><b>false: </b>If external storage is not writable</li>
 *         </ul>
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {

    boolean isWriteable = false;
    try {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can write the media
            isWriteable = true;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            // We can only read the media but we can't write
            isWriteable = false;
        } else {
            // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other
            // states, but all we need
            // to know is we can neither read nor write
            isWriteable = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return isWriteable;
}
```

Add following permissions in Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also check whether you have enabled sd-card for emulator:

Go to `'Android Virtual Device Manager'(AVD)` and click on your Emulater then press `'Edit'` button. In `'Hardware'` section, check whether you have added `'SD card support = yes'`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and report back!

Comment: both returned false? What should I do to make them both return true. How do I mount the SD Card in my emulator.

Comment: I have =,( It is still return false

Comment: Go to 'Android Virtual Device Manager'(AVD) and click on your Emulater then press 'Edit' button. In 'Hardware' section, check whether you have added 'SD card support = yes'

Comment: That is it! Thanks Muhammad, you are a star!